# image button with overlay

Tags: html, css

Almost  at the bottom of the page you see 4 images with a button inside of each image. (Verona, Mono Silk, Fibre Silk and Akvarell).

I'm trying to achieve an image, with a centered (both veritically and horizontally) text inside of it. And it all needs to be responsive.

The most important thing that I need to fix with these buttons though is that when you hover over a button, I want the image to become darker (just like it is now) but I want it to stay that way even when you hold the mouse over the text inside. I don't understand which approach I need to have to achieve that.

The html code for a button is:

```css
.product-container {
    position:relative;
    background-color: #000000;
    }

    .product-btn {
    position: absolute;
    top:39%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.3);
    width: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 5px 0;
    }

    .product-img {
    width:100%;
    height: auto;
    opacity: 1; 
 transition:
    opacity 0.1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.1s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.1s ease-in-out;
    }

    .product-img:hover {opacity: 0.5;}
```

```html
    <div class="product-container">
    <img class="product-img" src="http://dev2015.proformat.se/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/monosilk.jpg"/>
    <a href="http://google.se">
        <p class="product-btn">Mono Silk</p>
    </a>
    </div>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have the image darker when hover both image and text, I changed this CSS rule

```
.product-img:hover {opacity: 0.5;}
```

to this

```
.product-container:hover img {opacity: 0.5;}
```

You also had an extra closing `</div>` tag which I removed.

<strike>Having block level (`p`) element inside an inline (`a`) is invalid, so I changed your `p` to a `span` and added `text-align: center;` to its CSS rule so the text inside is centered.</strike>

Having block level element, like `p`, inside an inline element is in general invalid, though according to the new [HTML5 specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element), an `a` now can have block level elements inside (Thanks to @tjameswhite pointing that out), as long as there is no interactive content within (e.g. buttons or other links).

Sample snippet

```css
.product-container {
  position:relative;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.product-btn {
  position: absolute;
  top:39%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.3);
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 5px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.product-img {
  width:100%;
  height: auto;
  opacity: 1; 
  transition:
    opacity 0.1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.1s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.1s ease-in-out;
}

.product-container:hover img {opacity: 0.5;}
```

```html
<div class="product-container">
  <img class="product-img" src="http://dev2015.proformat.se/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/monosilk.jpg">
  <a href="http://google.se">
    <span class="product-btn">Mono Silk</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This did the trick! I had to put the image inside the <a> tag then everything worked just as I wanted it too!

Comment: Actually you can put a <p> inside of <a> if you are using HTML5.

Comment: @tjameswhite Yes, you can, still, it is invalid and will give an error/warning when run through a validator.

Comment: @LGSon Yeah, the validators still mark it as wrong even though in HTML5 it is valid. Check out the example at the end of the section: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element

Comment: @tjameswhite I actually have missed that the HTML5 specs allow block element inside anchors ... so you are absolutely correct

Comment: @tjameswhite Updated my answer, thanks for the comment

Answer (score 0):

Change the Markup so that image comes after the link.

Then css will get the link to be in center of parent:

```css
.product-container {
      position:relative;
      background-color: #000000;
    }
    
    .product-btn {
      position: absolute;
      top:50%;
      left: 50%;
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.3);
      width: 50%;
      border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
      color: #ffffff;
      padding: 5px 0;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
    
    .product-img {
      width:100%;
      height: auto;
      opacity: 1; 
      transition:
      opacity 0.1s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: opacity 0.1s ease-in-out;
      -webkit-transition: opacity 0.1s ease-in-out;
    }
    
    .product-container > a:hover + img {opacity: 0.5;}
```

```html
    <div class="product-container">
      <a href="http://google.se">
        <p class="product-btn">Mono Silk</p>
      </a>
      <img class="product-img" src="http://dev2015.proformat.se/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/monosilk.jpg"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In CSS (slow the style change in product-container and make hover action for it):

```
.product-container {position:relative; background-color: #000000;
    transition: opacity 0.1s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: opacity 0.1s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: opacity 0.1s ease-in-out;
}
/*.product-img:hover {opacity: 0.5;}*/
.product-container:hover img {opacity: 0.5;}
```

In HTML (put link inside the .product-container div):

```
<div class="product-container"><img class="product-img" src="./Material _ ProFormat AB_files/monosilk.jpg"/><a href="http://google.se/"><p class="product-btn">Mono Silk</p></a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the markup so the image and text are inside of the link:

```
<div class="col-sm-3 text-center">
    <a href="http://google.se" class="product-container">
        <img class="product-img" src="http://dev2015.proformat.se/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/monosilk.jpg" alt="">
       <div class="product-btn">Mono Silk</div>
   </a>
</div>
```

This removes an extra container (moving the product-container class to the link). Then update styles to something like:

```
.product-container {
    position:relative;
    background-color: #000000;
    display: block;
    height: 426px;
    width: 426px;
 }

 .product-img {
     width: 426px;
     height: 426px;
 }
 .product-btn {
     position: absolute;
     top: 39%;
     left: 0;
     right: 0;
     margin: 0 auto;
     background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.3);
     width: 50%;
     border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
     color: #ffffff;
     padding: 5px 0;
     text-align: center;   
 }

 .product-container:hover .product-img {opacity: 0.5;}
 .product-container:hover .product-btn {background: rgba(0,0,0,1)}
```

Note that the link (`.product-container`) has `display: block;` and a set width and height, as does the image. Adjust as needed.

The advantage to this is that the entire box is now one big clickable button.

Comment: I love the result of this too. But isn't there some kind of way to get the button to be 100% width, and the height to be the same value as the width? maybe with some javascript or something? I don't want the size of the buttons to be static!

Comment: Sure you could experiment with %, or Flex box, even some JS to size it.

Answer (score 0):

A cool trick is using pseudo elements to vertically align inline blocks. This allows for multiple lines of text to also be aligned properly.

I apologise as I'm at work at the moment, so I hope this fiddle helps.
Will go into more detail in an update later if requested:

https://jsfiddle.net/pj5p0s3s/

```css
/*Disgusting stuff for demo :) */
.product-container {
  float:left;
  margin-right:5px;
  max-width:200px;
 }
 /* */

.product-container {
  position:relative;
  background-color: #000000;
}
.product-container a {
   display:block;
}
.product-container a:after {
  content:"";
  background: rgba(0,0,0, 0.3);
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
}
.product-container a:hover:after {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.product-container-overlay {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  text-align:center;
  z-index:1;
}
.product-container-overlay:before {
  content:"";
  height:100%;
  display:inline-block;
  width:1px;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

.product-btn {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.3);
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 5px 0;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

.product-img {
  width:100%;
  height: auto;
  display:block;
}

.product-img:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-container">
  <a href="http://google.se">
    <div class="product-container-overlay">
      <p class="product-btn">Mono Silk</p>
    </div> 
    <img class="product-img" src="http://dev2015.proformat.se/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/monosilk.jpg"/>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="product-container">
  <a href="http://google.se">
    <div class="product-container-overlay">
      <p class="product-btn">Mono Silk long title lipsum</p>
    </div> 
    <img class="product-img" src="http://dev2015.proformat.se/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/monosilk.jpg"/>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="product-container">
  <a href="http://google.se">
    <div class="product-container-overlay">
      <p class="product-btn">Mono Silk</p>
    </div> 
    <img class="product-img" src="http://dev2015.proformat.se/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/monosilk.jpg"/>
  </a>
</div>
```